# how to reverse a whole sequece of data

Tags: awk

How do you reverse a whole sequence of data using awk? For instance, given a sample of data blow. How do I reverse the whole sequence of data. I try

```
awk '{print}' test.txt | rev>test1.txt
```

But it is reversing line by line. How do I fix it so it reverses the whole data not line by line?

```
TACCCAAAAGCACCCAAAATGCTTGAAAAAAACGTGATCGCTGACCACAAAGCGGATAGGCCGAAACTAAT

ACTTGACTTTTTTGTAAAATTGGTCTATCCTCCCCGTTCTTTGTTTCCGTGGCGGGAGACAAAGCGGTTACAGATCAACGAACAATGGGAATAGGGTTAGTAAAAGGGGG
CATTTATATATACTATGGCAGAAATAAACTACGAATCTTCATCTTTTAAGGCGCCGCTGCACCACCGAATTTTGGCAAATATGCCAGTGCAGGCAAGCTGGGTTGACGAA
AAAACGGGACGTCGGGTCAAAGTAGATGGCGTTACGGAAAATCTCGGTCAAACCAGTGCACTGGTAAATCT
CGAAATCCTTCCGCCGGTTGGCTCGGAGGTAAAACTCAAAATTCTTGGCGAGGACAAGCCGATAATTGAAG
TATCGGCGGAAGTTATCCGAGTTGAACGTGACCCAAGCAAACCGCTTGCTGCACTTTCAATTCTCCAGAATTTGAAAAAGTGGAAAACAACGGCGATGGAGGCCGCGCAA
GCTTGGGTTACGCGGCATTGGCAATTAAACTACGAAGAGGAATGGGTTAATTAACCCGGCATCTTCTCTT

AAAACCGTAGCTTGAGCGGAGATTCGGCTTTCCTGCCCGATTCTCCGCTTTCGATTTTTCTGCCTACCGCAAGGGCCAAACGGCCATAATAGCAACATATGCCTCTAGACG
```

Comment: did you try ````tac````command

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine, maybe you should try using `unbuffer awk '{print}' test.txt | rev>test1.txt `

Comment: i try again and it worked. I don't know I must have done something before that case it not to work

Comment: @user11766958, that's good. It would be a good idea to delete the question maybe or if there is something extra you did, answer your question.

Comment: Okay I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you absolutely want to use awk for that when you can combine `tac` *(for the lines order)* and `rev` *(for the characters order)*:

```
tac test.txt | rev
```